# Any GL transformation not working

Tags: opengl, c++

Today I was trying to make a test camera, with a new method(I usually use gluLookAt)

So I got a problem,

```
void GameDraw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.001, 10000.0);
    pitch += 1;
    glRotatef(pitch, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(yaw, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    s->bind();
    test->drawMesh();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

And my draw function is:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

if it isn't working with glDrawElements is there any alternative to use?

Edit: Disabling shader it works fine, but how I can use this with Shader

Please don't use glm examples, because I don't like to use it, I feel more comfortable by using the my math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: Disabling shader it works fine, but how I can use this with Shader

There is you problem, the default shader gets and uses the matrix stack but your shader probably doesn't. You should multiply the position with `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` in the vertex shader:

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
```

The Matrix stack was removed in modern opengl (core version 3.1+) however, which requires you to use a 3rd party lib for your matrix math on cpu and use uniforms to pass it to the shader.

Comment: "The Matrix stack was removed in modern opengl (core version 3.1+) however, which requires you to use a 3rd party lib for your matrix math on cpu and use uniforms to pass it to the shader." I believe calling glGet for all 3 matrices, and passing them to the shader, I think it may not require. So my idea will work?(I'm questioning this because if I start something in my code, and remove after, it will be a buggy mess in my code)

Comment: It's not that hard to duplicate the opengl matrix stack. Even to give it mostly the same api.

Comment: glGet on matrix will return an 16 element array, to the opengl I pass 2D array of matrice? Or works with 16 too?

Comment: Opengl expects the 16 element array

Comment: no matter if is flat or not?

Comment: GLfloat matrix[16];
 glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
 s->passUniformMatrix4(&matrix[0], "myMatrix");// now it isn't drawing my model :(